# How do I solve this integration problem?

Tags: calculus, integration

The question is- Find $\int\frac{\sec^xx}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$

What I've tried:
$$\int\frac{\sec^{x-2}x\sec^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$$

Let $\tan x = t$.

$$\int\frac{\sec^{x-2}x}{\sqrt{t\,}}dt$$

What should I do next? Any sort of help is appreciated.

Comment: it is $$\int\frac{\sec(x)}{\sqrt{\tan(x)}}dx?$$

Comment: Are you sure that this should be $\sec ^{\color{red}{x}} x$? Perhaps you mean $\sec ^{\color{red}{n}} x$? How would you even define $\sec^x(x)$ in regions where $x \not\in\Bbb Z$, $\sec(x)<0$?

Comment: I have checked and my question is correct.

Comment: I do not understand the reason for the down votes. My question is legit.

Comment: It is not possible to evaluate this integral in terms of standard mathematical functions, according to wolfram alpha. Also your substitution doesn't make much sense, since you still have $x$'s in your integral, which should have been changed out for things in terms of $t$ (which would give an unpleasant $\arctan (t)$ in an exponent). Do you not even have any limits? Even then I don't see there being much hope.

Comment: @JohnDoe No limits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Integrands of the form $f^x(x)$ usually have no closed-form antiderivative, by the Liouville theorem.

The probability that your problem statement is wrong equals $1-\epsilon$.

And IMO the probability that the true question is

$$\int\frac{\sec^2x}{\sqrt{\tan x}}dx$$

equals $1+\epsilon$.

Comment: Wow!  A probability greater than $1$ sounds interesting.

Comment: @MarkViola: they call it "more than certainly".

Comment: Indeed.  But are you certain about what "they call it?"

Comment: Yves, in all seriousness, negative probabilities (and ones greater than 1) have applicability ([See This Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_probability)).

Comment: @MarkViola: less than impossibly ?

Comment: Yves, have a look at the article in the link I provided.  It's pretty interesting stuff.